# Reading very large file, would multi-threading in Java be of use here?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-spark

The functionality that I am trying to implement is:

1. Read file
2. validate each record (line)
3. store record to DB

I want record processing should happen in parallel. What I meant by this is, read a file by thread A, handle the line (record) to sub thread to validate and store in DB), while sub thread busy doing validation and storing, thread A continues to read file.

Basically what I don't want to happen is, read record, validate record and store record in sequential pattern.

My initial sketch is something like below;

1. Create a Pool of threads
2. Create Jobqueue.

As the main thread start reading file, every record that fetches will put into, as and when records are available in the queue the second part of the process should get record from queue and validate it and store them , then pick next available record and continue until it queue is empty.

Is this a right way of doing this, OR is there any better way of doing this? If so, would someone please suggest? Any tools / opensource that has functionality of this kind is also welcome. Bit of code snippet to get started with will be much appreciated.

Comment: That really should be I/O bound. Make sure you're not using individual transactions for each record. I believe sequentially reading files should cause it to be read ahead. Standard process: Get the simplest thing working first. Compare to back-of-envelope calculations. Profile.

Comment: Can the storing to the DB be done in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), which will create and manage the thread pool for you and also handle passing jobs to do (records to validate and write to the DB) to threads. You'd create it with an appropriate [`BlockingQueue<Runnable>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) implementation ([`ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html), [`LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html), etc.) along with the thread pool characteristics you want (core size, max size, etc.), then give it [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) tasks to do.

Creating the thread pool executor (**very** rough example):

```
// Core of 4 threads, up to 8 threads, 10 second keepalive
this.threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
    4, 8, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(),
    (task, executor) -> {
        // Handle the fact a task was rejected...
    }
);
```

Adding a job (**very** rough example):

```
final Record record = /*...read a record...*/;
this.threadPoolExecutor.execute(() -> {
    // ...code to validate and insert `record`...
});
```

That handles each record individually. It may make more sense to "chunk" them into groups of X records (5, 10, 100, whatever makes sense) so you can insert the entire chunk of records using a single transaction.

As [Boris the Spider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071828/boris-the-spider) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824887/reading-very-large-file-with-doing-it-can-multi-threading-in-java-help-me-here-o/56824982?noredirect=1#comment100202354_56824982), you may not want to allow the file read to get *massively* ahead of the validate/write process. In your case, since you're adding to the executor's work in just the one place, you might check to see if the queue is getting full and suspend the read process if it is. The executor provides a hook on task completion you can use to restart when the queue is back to a reasonable size. For instance, you might suspend reading when the queue has more than X outstanding tasks, and restart it from a hook when the number has gone down to something lower than X (often you have a gap between the high point where you suspend and the low point where you resume).

Comment: Worth noting that you'll want to limit queue size to avoid running out of memory and then switch the rejected task handler to "submitter runs" to apply back pressure to the reading process.

Comment: Could also do the whole lot with `runAsync`, but I don't think it gives you much.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - Good points both, given the "very large file" described by the question.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Java 8+, I'd suggest you stream the file in parallel & process it functional style.

Comment: Not a good idea - first, `parallel` streams are generally very slow compared to almost any alternative. Second, the way a parallel steam batches reads is completey hardcoded - you'll got 1k (I think, perhaps remember that wrong) line chunks at the most granular split. TL;DR: don't do this.